# Zend: Issues setting up editAction(), please advise

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am experiencing some difficulty setting up the functionality for an admin to edit an items values. I have created the `editAction()` function in the `AdminItemController` class. This is contained within a module called `catalog`. My routing is configured as the following:

```
resources.router.routes.admin-catalog-edit.route = "/admin/catalog/item/edit/:id"
resources.router.routes.admin-catalog-edit.defaults.module = "catalog"
resources.router.routes.admin-catalog-edit.defaults.controller = "admin.item"
resources.router.routes.admin-catalog-edit.defaults.action = "edit"
```

I have created a custom Zend_Form class and within this class I set the action and method for the form:

```
class My_Form_ItemAdd extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAction('/admin/catalog/item/edit')
             ->setMethod('post');
        ...
```

Within my controller action I have instantiated the form and pass it to the view to be rendered. I also test if it's a POST (if so validate and save to database), otherwise, test for GET (if so, extract ID and `populate()`):

```
class Catalog_AdminItemController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
    public function editAction()
    {
        $form = new My_Form_ItemEdit();
        $this->view->form = $form;
        ...
```

The form loads just fine in the browser when I supply an ID at the end for GET request... however, when I submit the form an exception is thrown with the following request parameters:

```
array (
    'controller' => 'admin',
    'action' => 'catalog',
    'item' => 'edit',
    'module' => 'default',
    ...
```

I have no idea why the it would be doing this... is there something I'm not seeing??? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your route. The default behavior for `/admin/catalog/item/edit/:id` is to process it like `/controller/action/:param/:param/:param` which puts both `item` and `edit` as parameters instead of your intended purpose. Try adding something like this to your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    // Get front controller
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    // Get router
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    // Add route
    $router->addRoute(
            'admin_item_edit',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin/catalog/item/edit/:id',
                                        array('controller' => 'item',
                                              'action' => 'edit'))
    ); 

}
```

This allows you to define the specific controller and action from the route.